# How to print "TEST PASSED" in DB2 query

Tags: sql, database, db2

I would like you to ask, how to add IF_ELSE or CASE statement which prints out answer IF TEST PASSED or FAILED?

-- Every argument should be matched 1:1

-- In case of the result 0 ---> "TEST PASSED"

-- Otherwise               ---> "TEST FAILED"

```
select COUNT(*) AS RESULT from (
SELECT 
distinct T1.PROJECT_NO,
T1.START,
D.DATE,
T1.STATUS

FROM TEAM AT
JOIN PROJECT T1
ON AT.GROUP_ID = T1.ROW_ID 
AND T1.MARKED <> 'Y'
JOIN TRIP D
ON T1.ROW_ID = D.ROW_ID
AND D.MARKED <> 'Y'
where STATUS in ('active')

INTERSECT

select L.PROJECT_NO, L.START, L.DATE, 'active' as STATUS 
from TARGET_TABLE L with ur );
```

Many thanks for every response.

Comment: It is not clear *what* you want to test. What is the statement you want to verify? It should be something like "every project with status active and marked Y does only have trips marked Y" or "every project in status active that has at least one trip marked Y is also marked Y" or ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE count(*)
         WHEN 0 THEN
           'TEST PASSED'
         ELSE
           'TEST FAILED'
       END RESULT
       ...
```